# Can my application be automated with Selenium?

Tags: angular, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

We are trying to automate an application with the [Angular](https://angular.io/) front-end and the [ngx-Boostrap css](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/) framework. Is there any way to know if an application can be automated with Selenium or not?

I ask this, because we are having some difficulty in locating the elements. I talked to a colleague and she asked me to test it first with Selenium IDE, in case it worked, the application could be automated with Selenium WebDriver. That's true?

Comment: use protractor for angular project else you should use explicit waits in selenium

Comment: @PDHide Whenever you answered my questions, there was always an answer to my problem! But, about explicit waiting, it is not necessarily a problem. Now find certain elements, yes.

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant

Comment: what issues are you having with locating elements?  are you saying that certain elements you can't even grab by xPath? I think what @PDHide was referencing was to use explicit waits in the case that elements aren't immediately visible

Comment: For example, are there applications that are not possible to use Selenium?

Comment: Web apps? Not that I know of.  Maybe someone smarter than me can chime in on that though

Comment: Is there a particular problem you're having with selenium?

Comment: @DMart It would not be a technical problem in itself, but a question about the limits of the Selenium WebDriver

Comment: if it's in a browser selenium can help automate it. To what degree, depends on the application structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.
Selenium uses the html and css of your page to interact with and automates browser behaviour. If your app run in the browser, you can use selenium to automate it.

To make this easier, and more stable, I would recommend certain things as you build the app: Make sure you add either Id's or test-data attributes to your elements.

Use classes to manipulate styling, and use these for any and all important elements you want to interact with.
Bootstrap and angular are no objection for this in any way.
Then it should be easy to locate your elements, and your test code will be much cleaner and better maintainable.

Wheter you want to use selenium wrapped in something like protractor, codecept, use it with java, javascript python or whatever, are just choices. All of them work, whatever you know best, whatever the developers as a team know best so you can easily work together would be my recommendation.

Comment: So, as I understand it, is there no exception to the application of Selenium in SPA applications? Right?